# Can't Access Admin CP on nopCommerce v2.60

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have gone [here on CodePlex](http://goo.gl/DiIvF) and downloaded nopCommerce v2.60. I am on a Windows 8 Pro 64x Machine, I have .NET Framework and SQLEXPRESS 2012 installed.

The nopCommerce solution installs perfectly fine, no problem ! All front-end stuff work fine. But when I try and access:

> localhost:xxxx/admin

I get the following error:

[image]

I have already tried re-installing with fresh database and files, but no success. I don't know how to get it to work. Before this use to work no problems at all!

Comment: Try to open "localhost:2619"

Comment: Like mentioned, that works fine, it is just when I try access the admin side of things that I get the error.

Comment: Please check http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/717/opening-administration.aspx,http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/12295/how-to-launch-admin-panel-from-visual-studio-10.aspx

Comment: No help I'm afraid. That discussion was for nopCommerce web forms, not MVC. Plus none of that seems to relate to my setup. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after an exchange of emails with a friend of mine who is really good at C# and has excellent experience with nopCommerce. He too was able to duplicate the problem on his machine running Win 8 Pro 64x along with VS 2012, like me.

It turned out, for some strange reason, one must build, and re-build the solution a couple of times before running it in VS 2012.

So open up your nopCommerce fresh in VS2012, and before you run it, re-build the solution 2 or 3 times, and then run it.

That was the fix for me. So annoying that I spent so much time stuck with it, but I'm glad it works now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to BUILD the whole solution before running. :)

Comment: I am building the whole thing before running it. :(

Comment: Here's a few thing you can do:

1. Rebuild the whole solution.
2. Put a breakpoint at the Index() action of HomeController of Nop.Admin. See if breakpoint is hit!

Comment: i have same problem since i install visual studio 2012 and i also have VS 2010 . i rebuild solution many times and run it but still admin side not working and breakpoint is also not hitting index method of home controller. Give solution thanks...