# Nopcommerce 2.40 Cant access admin panel

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I am working on nopcommerce 2.40. I have newly installed VS2012 on my machine.

I opened my solution on VS2010 and suddenly admin side isnt working. It shows resource cannot be found.

I have gone through following link [Can't Access Admin CP on nopCommerce v2.60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762575/cant-access-admin-cp-on-nopcommerce-v2-60). But I want to open my application in VS2010 only as I normally do.

Any Solutions?

when i run website all user side working well, but when i try to access admin panel UI its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Could be many things giving you this error. If your'e runing on windows 8 like the link you provided and have rebuild your application a few times you could probably exclude that. Have you made anny changes in the web.config / connectionstrings? Are your database properly installed? Are you using the source code, could you access admin before?

Comment: I am not using Win8 its Win7 and nothing changed. Only thing is i have installed VS2012

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and then rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer (After more than one year.). Hope this helps somebody.

Found it [HERE](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/15011/cant-access-admin-in-v24-if-mvc4-is-loaded.aspx)

> The reference in Admin to System.Web.MVC got updated to 4, so I
>   removed it and re-added it from the Packages -> aspnetmvc folder. This
>   then matched the version in the Web folder, so admin appeared ok once
>   I'd cleaned and re-built.